# How to open a "Bootstrap modal dialog" with variable parameters

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, gallery

Gallery html code:

```
<div id="imgGallery" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/sesveuG_rNo/400x300" name="bear" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AvhMzHwiE_0/400x300" name="birds" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/2gYsZUmockw/400x300" name="pig" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EMSDtjVHdQ8/400x300" name="rabbits" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code for find and sending gallery name to php:

```
$('.info').click(function() {
    var galleryName = $(this).closest('#imgGallery').find('img.img-thumbnail').attr('name');
    $.ajax({
        url: "gallery/testingGallery/imgFinder.php",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            galleryName: galleryName
        },
        success: function(xhr) {
            console.log(xhr.imgNormal);
            console.log(xhr.imgThumb);
            console.log(xhr.imgCount);
            $("#galleryModal").modal('show');
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            console.log("Some error found");
        }
    });
});
```

PHP code for find directory, images and count images:

```
<?php
$dirname = $_POST["galleryName"];

$imgGallery = glob($dirname . "/".$dirname."_*.*");
$thumbGallery = glob($dirname . "/thumb_*.*");

$countImages = count($imgGallery);

echo json_encode(array("imgNormal" => $imgGallery, "imgThumb" => $thumbGallery, "imgCount" => $countImages));
?>
```

Now, on click **a.info** need open bootstrap modal dialog with variables, accepted in JS from PHP:
Need create as much **li**, as we **imgCount** get from PHP, with image sources **imgNormal** & **imgThumb**

In modal dialog for example, there is such a structure:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="clearfix" style="max-width:474px;">
            <ul id="vertical">
                <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/bear/thumb_bear_1.jpg">
                    <img src="gallery/testingGallery/bear/bear_1.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/bear/thumb_bear_2.jpg">
                    <img src="gallery/testingGallery/bear/bear_2.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/bear/thumb_bear_3.jpg">
                    <img src="gallery/testingGallery/bear/bear_3.jpg" />
                </li>
                <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/bear/thumb_bear_4.jpg">
                    <img src="gallery/testingGallery/bear/bear_4.jpg" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS for customize modal dialog:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vertical').lightSlider({
      gallery:true,
      item:1,
      vertical:true,
      verticalHeight:295,
      vThumbWidth:50,
      thumbItem:8,
      thumbMargin:4,
      slideMargin:0
    });  
  });
```

P.S. I`m sorry for my English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you shouldn't use "imgGallery" as an id for multiple elements. You should use "imgGallery" as a class for each element you need it.

Change the HTML code as such:

```
<div id="imgGallery1" class="imgGallery col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/sesveuG_rNo/400x300" name="bear" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a href="#" class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery2" class="imgGallery col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/AvhMzHwiE_0/400x300" name="birds" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a href="#"  class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery3" class="imgGallery col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/2gYsZUmockw/400x300" name="pig" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a href="#"  class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="imgGallery4" class="imgGallery col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeInUp hovereffect" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="https://source.unsplash.com/EMSDtjVHdQ8/400x300" name="rabbits" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h2>Effect 14</h2>
        <a href="#"  class="info">Show More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your modal body, remove all the li elements like this:

```
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="clearfix" style="max-width:474px;">
                    <ul id="vertical">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Finally, you will need to dynamically create the HTML inside the ul element of the modal.
Change your click handler code to:

```
<script>
        $('.info').click(function() {
            // change closest('#imgGallery') to closest('.imgGallery')
            var galleryName = $(this).closest('.imgGallery').find('img.img-thumbnail').attr('name');
            // reset modal body list html
            $('#vertical').html('');

            $.ajax({
                url: "gallery/testingGallery/imgFinder.php",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    galleryName: galleryName
                },
                success: function(xhr) {
                    console.log(xhr.imgNormal);
                    console.log(xhr.imgThumb);
                    console.log(xhr.imgCount);

                    if (xhr.imgCount == 0) { // no images in gallery
                        console.log('Gallery \'' + galleryName + '\' has no images');
                        return;
                    }

                    var modalBodyContent = '';
                    // for every expected image, create list element with appropriate data
                    for (var i = 1; i <= xhr.imgCount; i++) {
                        modalBodyContent += ' <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/' + galleryName + '/thumb_' + galleryName + '_' + i + '.jpg">' +
                            ' <img src="gallery/testingGallery/' + galleryName + '/' + galleryName+'_' + i + '.jpg"/> ' +
                        '</li>';
                    }
                    // set new modal body list html
                    if (modalBodyContent !== '') {
                        $('#vertical').html(modalBodyContent);
                        $("#galleryModal").modal('show');
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr) {
                    console.error("Some error found");
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

PS: Don't forget to add id "galleryModal" to your modal or nothing will show.

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Modal opened with content, I see this content with help "Inspect Element", but images not showing if not resize window of browser.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is exactly but I am guessing it is either the modal html code or your bootstrap include. I tested with these: 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: And not showing vertical thumbs on right of the modal. Can you see and test on my website? grandhuntings.com

Comment: imgFinder.php returns this result: 
{"imgNormal":["bear\/bear_1.jpg","bear\/bear_2.jpg","bear\/bear_3.jpg","bear\/bear_4.jpg"],"imgThumb":["bear\/thumb_bear_1.jpg","bear\/thumb_bear_2.jpg","bear\/thumb_bear_3.jpg","bear\/thumb_bear_4.jpg"],"imgCount":4}
You should change the html generation code to something like this: 
modalBodyContent += ' <li data-thumb="gallery/testingGallery/' + xhr.imgThumb[i-1] + '">' + ' <img src="gallery/testingGallery/' + xhr.imgNormal[i-1] + '"/> ' +
'</li>';

Comment: Same situation, need resize windows :(

Comment: hm :( I forget add other script for this modal modification:    
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#vertical').lightSlider({
                gallery: true,
                item: 1,
                vertical: true,
                verticalHeight: 295,
                vThumbWidth: 50,
                thumbItem: 8,
                thumbMargin: 4,
                slideMargin: 0
            });
        });
    </script>